# Accidentally used salted butter

Tags: baking, salt, brownies

I'm making some brownies for my nieces church school and I accidentally used salted butter and my batter is incredibly salty. Is there any way I can counter the saltiness of it? I'd hate to waste a it.

Comment: saltiness can't really be "countered", you might dilute and/or add a balancing flavor (like caramel), though that's less effective if the difference is large enough to be "incredible".  Out of curiosity, how did just salty butter make the batter incredibly salty, some specific brand? Usually salted butter is noticeable but I haven't come across any salty enough to oversalt batter that, that much.

Comment: Are you sure the batter is too salty? There's usually just 1 g salt per 100 g butter in salted butter. As most brownie recipes ask for salt anyway, it doesn't really matter whether you use unsalted butter with a pinch of salt or salted butter without that pinch.

Comment: Same brownies? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/no-sugar-in-brownies

Comment: I'd too guess that you might have used salt instead of white sugar to get "incredibly salty". // If it is just double salt then mix in another batch of brownie batter without any salt. You'll end up with two good batches.

Answer (score 4):

I use salted butter all the time in my baking and never "incredibly salty" results.  I think you must have used salt instead of sugar perhaps in your recipe to get that result.  Try it again with salted butter and make sure you use "sugar" that is called for in the recipe and it will be just fine.

Comment: This is the Occam's Razor answer.